# OpenVPN cannot reach others after a while

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn

I am using OpenVPN on a Debian 8 machine to secure some configuration sites of my server. I used the official HOWTO from the community site. After starting the service everything works fine, but just for a while. It takes something like 2 days that I am not able to reach/ping the host anymore while I am still able to establish the VPN connection.

I have no idea what kind of settings can be causing this. I hope this is just an error in the OpenVPN setup I am not seeing atm.

server.conf:

```
port XXXX
proto udp
dev tun

ca  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert    /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem

server 10.9.8.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.9.8.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
max-clients 10
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log openvpn.log
verb 3
```

client.ovpn: (Windows 10 Pro)

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

remote myhostname.net XXXX             # VPN server IP : PORT
nobind

ca      "ca.crt"
cert    "client.crt"
key     "client.key"

comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun

remote-cert-tls server
verb 3
```

Please feel free to ask for any configuration/log file you think it can causes a behavior like this. Thanks in advance for any tip!

Comment: So a W10 machine will be connected with no problems for 2 days with that setup and all is good and it stops passing traffic -- even though it lookos like its up?  What do the server logs say?

Comment: Sorry for my late response, it were full weeks.. With verb 7 on the server my serverlog is full of these lines:https://pastebin.com/bQ5Xydhz
You have any ideas?

Comment: I should mention that I disabled ipv6 through sysctl and my provider only gives me an ipv4.

Comment: That logfile shows the server trying to match traffic to the ipv6 link-local address of the interface (it should match something in your ifconfig).  Should be harmless, but maybe your ip6 isn't as disabled as you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't address your question (it would be hard to say what might be causing your timeout without a packet capture) but there are several options in the config file to restart a connection if it stops passing traffic. For example: `ping-restart` will restart the VPN tunnel if it stops passing (ping) traffic:

`ping 30`
`ping-restart 300`

On a client this will check the server connection over the control channel *if* no traffic (other than a key negotiation or TLS overhead) has passed in 30 seconds (the `ping 30` line) and restart the connection after 5 minutes of unsuccessful "pings" (note that these aren't ICMP pings...)
In a server config this would monitor each client connection separately, it wouldn't restart the entire server process.